# How to get friend list from Facebook using Android Facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app on facebook and achieve some first steps for implementing Facebook SDK.

This is what I'm trying to do: get list of friends from Facebook and to be able to pick some friends from that list and import them to my app.

How an I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you trying to get the Facebook friendlist of the user logged in into your app? Sounds like you need to perform a facebook graph request to acquire that list, and then withdraw the friends you want.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friendlists/

If you wanted to do it in Android java, her is an example:

```
    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArrayFriends = jsonObject.getJSONObject("friendlist").getJSONArray("data");
                    JSONObject friendlistObject = jsonArrayFriends.getJSONObject(0);
                    String friendListID = friendlistObject.getString("id"); 
                    myNewGraphReq(friendListID);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("fields", "friendlist", "members");
    graphRequest.setParameters(param);
    graphRequest.executeAsync();
```

Since "member" is an edge in "friendlist" you can do a new request with your friendlist Id to get the members of that particular friend list. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/members/

```
private void myNewGraphReq(String friendlistId) {
    final String graphPath = "/"+friendlistId+"/members/";
    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(token, graphPath, null, HttpMethod.GET, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
            JSONObject object = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
            try {
                JSONArray arrayOfUsersInFriendList= object.getJSONArray("data");  
                /* Do something with the user list */
                /* ex: get first user in list, "name" */
                JSONObject user = arrayOfUsersInFriendList.getJSONObject(0);
                String usersName = user.getString("name");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
     Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("fields", "name");
    request.setParameters(param);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

In the documentation for Facebook Graph request you can see what you can do with the User objects. I don't have enough rep to post another link unfortunately.

Keep in mind that a user must have signed in with facebook to get the access token needed to do these operations.

Well, hope it was something remotely like this you were looking for.

Edit: this method does not work anymore, the first link about friendlists shows that it is deprecated since 4 April 2018.

Comment: Wow, you have explained this really in detail. I don't want to user have relations with facebook. I just want to enable for user that he can import some birthdays of his friends from facebook. And i have put some icon of facebook in my MainActivity and when i click on that i would show new activity and in that activity i would insert this code, right?

Comment: Actually, if you want the birthday of a user from the friend list you need to ask for extra permission from facebook. Take a look at "user_birthday" her : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-user_birthday 
But if you had that permission, you could do the same as above, you would just switch user.getString("name"); with user.getString("birthday");

But you said you didnt want the user to log in with facebook or get any access token from them? Cause then this code would not work because you need an access token to play around with facebook information.

Comment: Okay, it's no problem if user is need to log in to facebook. Well without that user wouldn't get list of his friends, so how could i do something like this. I would click on that icon and then i would open a new activity as dialog and firstly i would ask for login to facebook and then i would show the list of his friends. And is there by default list with checkboxes so i could check what friend do i want to import?

Comment: Hmm, I guess you would need to keep the ID of the facebook users you wanted to show. So when you acquired the friend list from graph request above, you could loop through it, and only add the users with the wanted IDs into the list you are going to show to screen. But the best would be to just use this graph request the first time they log in, and then just save it on your own databse, so the next time they want to access the birthday list, they would not have to wait for the graph request again.

Comment: I have already create a database where i'm storing everything i need and i was thinking i could do it like this: because the date of birthday is stored as string, i would store from Json array string i get and insert it to database. I would do the same for name and last name. And when i'm calling this function you have created, what string i'm passing as argument?

Comment: If you are talking about the second method, the string is the ID of the friendlist you are looking at. You get this from first method. If you are going to use facebook information, I advise you to look into Graph request. A lot og handy information to get there.

Comment: Can i add you on google hangouts if you have or continue here a disscussion at chat, so i can ask you a few questions about facebook sdk if you have a time. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94863/discussion-between-dusan-dimitrijevic-and-brunbjorn).

Comment: You have a minor typo here (Acces**S**Token): AccesToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

Comment: graphResponse.getJSONObject(); returns null.

Comment: `param.putString("fields", "friendlist", "members");` throws a compiler error

Comment: It seems there is no more `members` in Facebook graph api