# Is there any possible to get the Facebook friends list by using messenger / Facebook SDK right now

Tags: android

Is there any possible to get the Facebook friends list by using messenger / Facebook SDK right now

I'm trying this below code Getting 200 and null error for friends list

new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/taggable_friends")

Comment: see this doc reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list/

Comment: Facebook SDK do not provide any APK's to access the friend list of a particular user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656046/how-to-get-friend-list-from-facebook-using-android-facebook-sdk?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: https://github.com/sallySalem/Facebook-Friends-list

Comment: Tq to all ...is there any possible to get the avatar for my friends list...getting only for ID and name itself .